# Trying to get instance of socket from zeromq pollitem

Tags: c++, sockets, zeromq

I'm working on an implementation of the zmq::poll that needs a very generalized, modular, and flexible way of checking multiple sockets. I'm trying to get the socket instance from the zmq::pollitem_t.

```
zmq::socket_t zsocX(context, ZMQ_PAIR);
zsocX.bind(addr);
zmq::pollitem_t item = {zsocX, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0};
((zmq::socket_t *)(item.socket))->send(msg);
```

I get the error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'zmq::error_t'
  what(): Socket operation on non-socket
```

Any idea what the issue is? It's my understanding that `zmq::pollitem_t::socket` is a `void *` that points on the socket.

Edit: The memory address changes. A suggestion that possibly the C API socket type is being used instead. Any solution?

```
// the following lines print different values
std::cout << "Main " << (&zsocMain) << std::endl;
std::cout << "Poll " << x.socket << std::endl;
```

Comment: Try using the C API instead. (void*)zsocX probably isn't returning the same pointer as &zsocX would. I bet (void*)zsocX gets the C API version of the socket.

Comment: @immibis Seems like it! See my edit to see `cout` returning different values. Any solution?

Comment: Try using the C API instead? I bet (void*)zsocX gets the C API version of the socket.

Comment: @immibis that does indeed see to be the case. But I lose access to the c++ wrapper functionality and it seems odd to use both APIs

Comment: @Frank did you solve this problem ? because I have exactly the same issue and I don't know what should I do.

Comment: @bladzio unfortunately not. I instead had to maintain a parallel array with the socket pointer stored so that if `vzPollItems[x].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN == true` I access `zmqsocklist[x].sock`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. The answer to my question may help you:

[ZeroMQ: How to cast a pollitem_t item, used in Poller, back to a ZeroMQ socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58639610/zeromq-how-to-cast-a-pollitem-t-item-used-in-poller-back-to-a-zeromq-socket)

In short, you could look into the `zmq::poller_t` as part of the *ZMQ DRAFT API*.