# ZeroMQ: How to cast a pollitem_t item, used in Poller, back to a ZeroMQ socket?

Tags: c++, sockets, zeromq

As title says, when using **`zmq::poll`** with `cppzmq`, I'd love to avoid  hardcoding the translation of ZeroMQ sockets into `pollitem_t item`(s) for polling.

But it seems that I'm not allowed to convert a `void*` `pollitem_t::socket` back to a zmq socket.

I noticed that the official sample code just hardcoded the socket after polling.

```cpp
//
//  Reading from multiple sockets in C++
//  This version uses zmq_poll()
//
// Olivier Chamoux <olivier.chamoux@fr.thalesgroup.com>

#include "zhelpers.hpp"

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    zmq::context_t context(1);

    //  Connect to task ventilator
    zmq::socket_t receiver(context, ZMQ_PULL);
    receiver.connect("tcp://localhost:5557");

    //  Connect to weather server
    zmq::socket_t subscriber(context, ZMQ_SUB);
    subscriber.connect("tcp://localhost:5556");
    subscriber.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "10001 ", 6);

    //  Initialize poll set
    zmq::pollitem_t items [] = {
        { static_cast<void*>(receiver), 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0 },
        { static_cast<void*>(subscriber), 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0 }
    };
    //  Process messages from both sockets
    while (1) {
        zmq::message_t message;
        zmq::poll (&items [0], 2, -1);
        
        if (items [0].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN) {
            receiver.recv(&message);
            //  Process task
        }
        if (items [1].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN) {
            subscriber.recv(&message);
            //  Process weather update
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Hence the question:

Is it impossible to avoid hardcoding sockets in this case?

Comment: How did you try casting `items[0].socket` back to a `zmq::socket_t` ?

Comment: `zmq::socket_t sock = static_cast<zmq::socket_t>(pollitem.socket);` either this or `zmq::socket_t* sock = static_cast<zmq::socket_t*>(pollitem.socket);`

Comment: Looking into zmq source, I noticed that there is only this cast: `zmq::socket_base_t *s = static_cast<zmq::socket_base_t *> (s_);` where `s_` is a `void*`.

Comment: Yes, `zmq::socket_t` has an `operator void*` that returns the handle, but there is no way of getting back to the socket.

Comment: @Botje What a pity. When polling in from a number of sockets, I'd really love to get a one-to-one mapping between the recv'ed messages and the sockets using a container like std::map. But this polling makes it so difficult to achieve. The only thing I can think of is to create another container of the known socket references and sync it with the poll items manually. Oh well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puzzled this together from the zmq.hpp header:

```
zmq::poller_t poller;
poller.add({from_handle, receiver.handle()}, event_flags::pollin});
poller.add({from_handle, subscriber.handle()}, event_flags::pollin});

// This vector must be at least as large as the number of sockets being polled
vector<zmq::poller_event> events(2);
while (true) {
  size_t num_events = poller.wait_all(events, -1);
  // You may need to sleep a bit if num_events == 0

  for (int i = 0; i < num_events; i++) {
    zmq::message message;
    events[i].socket.recv(&message);
    ...
  } 
}
```

EDIT: Realized that the `poller_event` structure also contains a `socket_ref`! That makes things even easier!

With a stable zmq release, you need to `#define ZMQ_BUILD_DRAFT_API` to use `poller_t` and its bag.

Comment: Since your answer solves my immediate problem, I turned to accept yours. Thank you!

Comment: ok, I see why I missed all this: `ZMQ_BUILD_DRAFT_API` is disabled by default.

Comment: someone please help... I'm not that experienced at `C++`. I use VS2022.. I use `v4.8.1` of `cppzmq` that was installed (and zeromq along with it) via `vcpkg`. Everything was working great until I found out I couldn't use `zmq::poller_t` - _namespace zmq has no member poller_t - anyhow, after hours of headscratching and googling I finally found this comment. Now I don't understand where to put this `#define ZMQ_BUILD_DRAFT_API. Can someone explain what I need to do? thanks

Comment: ah I got it to work, one of the library files was being included above my header and I had put my define in my header

Answer (score 1):

> **Q** : *Is it impossible to **avoid hardcoding** sockets in this case?*

Yes.

### **This is the WHY part** :

**1 )**
The API documented **`Poller`**-setup requires us to fill-in the **`pollitem_t item`**(s) into a mandatory data-structure the `Poller`-instance is expecting to receive from us. ( So this part is a MUST-HAVE one and there is ***no imaginable 
"avoidance"-trick possible here*** - opaque ***`void*`*** MUST be delivered to `Poller` so as to work as expected ... to indeed `.poll()` something ... )

**2 )**
A "reverse" transcoding ( hardcoded or not ) ***is not necessary*** ( thus there is not a thing to avoid here ), right due to the step 1 - your code already knows the "map" - it has generated the 1:1-map-of-`pollitem_t item`(s) for a mandatory delivery to the `Poller` under review.

---

### EPILOGUE :

For cases, where the **amount** of the `Socket`-instances, that happen to be a subject to the initial building of the **mandatory *( i.e. un-avoid-able )*** 1:1-map-of-`pollitem_t item`s data-structure ( which you started to call a "hardcoding" part ), one may design a scripted-tool for static cases ( for the case of known `Socket`-instances to be processed ) or an adaptive map-generator, that will consume your own managed pilot-"tape" ( your systematically maintained data-structure ) with all `Socket`-instances to be processed ).

Comment: Alright, in other words, I'd most likely need a 3-piece data to poll from a list of sockets by ID and recv messages into a map `std::map<MyID, zmq::message_t> myMsgs`: `std::map<MyID, zmq::socket_t> mySocks;`, `std::vector<zmq::pollitem_t> myPollers;`, `std::vector<MyID> myIDs`, since the poller must be an array. This seems cumbersome especailly when `pollitem_t` already has a socket in it, IMHO. I'd love to poll, then directly `myPollers[i].socket.recv(...)`. Is this too much to ask from a UX perspective?

Comment: Have you looked at the [`zmq_poller` API](http://api.zeromq.org/master:zmq-poller)? That allows you to attach a `void * userdata` to each individual socket.

Comment: @Botje AH, you are right! Thanks for the tip. I totally missed it! Would you make this an answer? I'd very much love to up vote it and make it the second accepted answer IF I could!

Comment: @Botje you may have noticed, that the API-doc for v4.3.2 has still a **wet ink**, the example code violates the just published call-signatures ( the comments were also remained unmodified ). The trick is just in making the above posted advice "inherited" into providing a pass-thru interface for passing a pointer to an object for de-mapping ( here via a user-data ) as was noted in the Epilogue section above. Q.E.D.

Comment: @user3666197 Just because the example is wrong does not mean the API is broken. I also do not understand anything of your last sentence.

Comment: @Botje of course it was not meant to fabulate a single point about the state of the API - the very contrary to that - it was explicit in telling the documentation has this as a sign of a wet ink ( meaning a quite fresh, new changes - sorry if a wet ink parallel was not clear to be understood at that ) **Long live the Zen-of-Zero :o)**

Comment: @user3666197 I just created https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/pull/3727 to dry some of that ink. Thanks for spotting it!